# Acceder a datos de una aplicacion en asp.net por medio de otra aplicacion en c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo un sistema hecho con asp y visual basic 2008, y tengo otra aplicacion en c#, deseo acceder a la primera aplicacion y poder hacer uso de sus metodos. ¿Como lo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Podes explicar un poco mejor que queres.. queres acceder a datos o al codigo de la otra app?

Comment: Adivinando... en tu caso lo que yo haria es crear una solucion, agregar los dos proyectos: el de ASP.NET y el de C#, y agregar la referencia del ASP en el c#, con eso ya tendrías acceso a sus clases.

Comment: Buenas, tengo un sistema de ventas en la primera aplicacion, que tiene definido funciones de insercion a una base datos, ahora tengo otra segunda aplicacion en c#, del cual necesito poder invocar a las funciones de insercion de la primera aplicacion, debido que la logica de insercion esta en esas funciones, lo que quiero es reutilizar esas funciones de la primera aplicacion.

Comment: Mueve todas las clases que necesitas que están en el proyecto asp.net a otro proyecto tipo dll, luego, en ambas aplucaciones, la de asp.net y la otra, agregas la referencia al dll que acabas de crear, y ya no tienes que meter la referencia del proyecto asp.net en la otra aplicación, solo al dll que creaate.